# Is there a default directory for generated sources in Android Gradle projects?

Tags: android, gradle, code-generation

In gradle projects that use the `java` plugin, `"${projectDir}/generated"` will automatically be added to the classpath (just like `"${projectDir}/src"`). As such, it does not need to be added to `sourceSets` explicitly in order for its contents to become usable.

Is there a similar directory for projects that use an Android plugin (e.g. `com.android.library`) which has a similar effect, i.e. that the `"${projectDir}/generated` equivalent directory does not need to be added to any `sourceSets` explicitly for it to work?

As far as I can tell, the [plugin docs](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Sourcesets-and-Dependencies) don't mention any such directory, but I'm not yet accepting that to be definitive proof that such a directory doesn't exist.

Comment: `build/generated/source/` is the same for `com.android.application` projects as it is for `com.android.library` projects. What difference are you seeing?

Comment: I'm looking for a folder that when I put e.g. assets into it, these will be packed into the resulting artifact (e.g. the APK). If I e.g. copy some files into `build/generated/assets/my/package`, those assets are unavailable in the packaged result.

Comment: Are you writing a plugin? For Java code, with the 2.x edition of the Android plugin DSL, you need to call `registerJavaGeneratingTask` on the build variant to teach the build system to include your generated code directory. The build system doesn't just grab all Java source in `build/generated/`. I would look for a similar mechanism to teach the build variant about a directory of assets to include.

Comment: I'm not writing a plugin. I'm looking for a way to copy sources/assets into my project in a way that follows convention, i.e. that these files cannot be mistaken for manually added. At the same time I would like to need a specialized `clean` task for clearing out such destination folders.

Comment: "I'm not writing a plugin" -- then perhaps you should be.